# MKMapView disable pin drags

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I'm loading data from an array and dropping pins for entries with a specified location. I'm doing this in my viewWillAppear method.

I add the pins by initializing annotations for the said entries and then adding them via

```
[userLocation addAnnotations: annotations];
```

However, I have noticed that I am still able to drag the pins around. Is there any way of preventing the user from dragging the pins from their predefined position? Thanks for your help.

viewWillAppear:

```
for(d=0;d<[eventArray count];d++){
    Entry *element=[eventArray objectAtIndex:d];
    float lon=[tmp.lon floatValue];
    float lat=[tmp.lat floatValue];
    if(lon!=0 && lat!=0){
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {lat, lon};
        MyAnnotation *annotation=[[MyAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:coord title:@"A  pin"];

        [userLocation addAnnotations: annotations];
    }
}
```

And then as suggested:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

MyAnnotation *annotationView = (MyAnnotation *)[self.userLocation dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Pin"];
if (annotationView == nil) {
    annotationView = [[[DDAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"] autorelease];
 //   annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
}
annotationView.draggable=NO;
return annotationView;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean, you are able to drag'n'drop the pins around? this should only be possible, when you enabled this before with `annotationView.draggable = YES;`.

Comment: @harakiri Hi, thanks for your comment, I drop the pins automatically in my viewWillAppear method, I tried using the code you suggested but I can't seem to figure out how to use it since I'm initializing an annotation, rather than an annotationView.

Comment: have a look at the `- (MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` delegate method of MKMapViewDelegate. Maybe this returns an `annotationView` with `draggable = YES`.

Comment: @harakiri Thanks, did try that as well no luck. :( I'm really drawing a blank.

Comment: Does `DDAnnotationView` overwrite the `draggable` property?! Just a guess.

Comment: I resolved it! Turns out I had to remove the - (MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation method. Apparently it sets the draggable property to yes. Thanks! :D

Comment: This delegate method itself doesn't set it to yes. I guess it's because you're using a Custom AnnotationView `DDAnnotationView` which maybe overwrites the `draggable` property.

Comment: @harakiri  Fair point, do you have an idea of how/where should I check?

Comment: I don't know all your code. Maybe you can provide the relevant classes via http://pastebin.com/.

Comment: @harakiri http://code.google.com/p/orientationapp/source/browse/trunk/StanfordEvents/Classes/DDAnnotation.h?r=3 http://code.google.com/p/orientationapp/source/browse/trunk/StanfordEvents/Classes/DDAnnotation.m?r=3 http://code.google.com/p/orientationapp/source/browse/trunk/StanfordEvents/Classes/DDAnnotationView.h?r=3http://code.google.com/p/orientationapp/source/browse/trunk/StanfordEvents/Classes/DDAnnotationView.m?r=3

Comment: OK, `DDAnnotationView` overwrites `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` etc and handles the drag'n'drop there ;)